# Qt : SetItemWidget to item before QTreeWidget becomes its parent?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to make a recursive function to fill a **QTreeWidget** from a JSON file.
It works great but I need to add a **spinbox** to the value column.

As you can see in the code, the function first creates the **QTreeWidgetItem**, then returns it to a prior instance, which in turn adds it to the tree's children, so the spinBox is not added : [image: QTreeWidget missing spinBox]

Is there a simple way to add it with minimal changes ?

```cpp
QTreeWidgetItem MainWindow::treeItemFromJson(QTreeWidgetItem* root, QJsonValue val){
    QJsonObject obj = val.toObject();
    foreach(const QString &key, obj.keys()){
        if(obj.value(key).isObject()){
            QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem({key});
            treeItemFromJson(item, obj.value(key));
            root->addChild(item); // item containing spinBox is set as child AFTER
        }
        else { // if the value stored in an object is not another object, then it is a setting

            switch(obj.value("Value").type()){
                case QJsonValue::Double  :
                    QSpinBox * spinBox;
                    spinBox = new QSpinBox();
                    spinBox->setRange(obj.value("Minimum").toInt(), obj.value("Maximum").toInt());
                    spinBox->setValue(obj.value("Value").toInt());
                    ui->settingsTree->setItemWidget(root, 1, spinBox);
                break;
                case QJsonValue::Bool :
                    QRadioButton * radioButton;
                    radioButton = new QRadioButton("test");
                    ui->settingsTree->setItemWidget(root, 1, radioButton);
                break;
                default :
                    root->setData(1, Qt::DisplayRole, obj.value("Value"));
                break;
            }

            root->setData(2, Qt::DisplayRole, obj.value("Unit"));
            root->setData(3, Qt::DisplayRole, obj.value("Description"));
            root->setData(4, Qt::DisplayRole, obj.value("Minimum"));
            root->setData(5, Qt::DisplayRole, obj.value("Maximum"));
            root->setData(6, Qt::DisplayRole, obj.value("Default"));
            root->setData(7, Qt::DisplayRole, obj.value("Identifier"));
        }
    }
    return *new QTreeWidgetItem; // useless
}
```

Comment: QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem(root, {key});  add the parent item. and  remove the ‘root->addChild(item); ’

Comment: @Ye.Feng thank you ! I solved it with the return value of the function that I didn't use yet.
Your solution is way better